# Joins Related Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables A and B.
A has a field say `ID,Name`.
B has two fields say `ID1 & ID2`.
In B the data for both the ID's comes from A's ID.
How can I join the two tables such that I get the corresponding name for the two ID's.
E.g

```
ID1 ID2 ID1NAME ID2NAME
1   2       X    Y
3   4       F    G
```

Regards,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show raw data from both tables?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  And then `JOIN` again.

Comment: i tried using left join to join the two table to get ID1's name and left join again with the entire new table created to get the ID2's name.

Comment: Please add table structures of both the tables in question. Don't add in comment.

Comment: @RahulSingh - that was the right approach, so what happened? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Join TableA twice on both Id1 and Id2 from TableB.

```
SELECT b.Id1
    ,b.Id2
    ,a1.Name AS Id1Name
    ,a2.Name AS Id2Name
FROM TableB b
JOIN TableA a1 ON a1.Id = b.Id1
JOIN TableA a2 ON a2.Id = b.Id2
```

May want to left join depending on if Ids are not always present in TableA.

Comment: You need to remove the single quotes from around the column aliases.

Comment: It works either way.  You're right, I technically don't need them... they are used for when the alias has a space in it like: ``'Id1 Name'``

Comment: No - single quotes are invalid as they signify a literal. If you want to use spaces, other special characters or to enforce case-sensitivity then you want double quotes around an identifier.

Comment: I've been using single quotes forever.  What issue is caused by using them for an alias?  Not arguing, would just like to educate myself on this. Removing them from the answer.

Comment: Not sure what you are using to run your queries but single quotes are a syntax error in SQL Developer and SQL/Plus and the query fails with `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`. Your IDE might be more permissive and automatically correct it.